# Application of Ito's Lemma to integral expression

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I have a problem applying Ito's lemma.

> I know that if: $dX_t= \mu_t \, dt + \sigma_t \, dB_t$ then for $f(t,x)$:
>
> $df(t,X_t) =\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \mu_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_t^2\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\right)dt+ \sigma_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dB_t$

Now I want to apply Ito's theorem to

$g:=∫_0^t \theta(u) \exp(-\alpha(t-u) ) dB(u)$ (background of this expression can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull%E2%80%93White_model))

How, if possible, can I do this?

The integral expression confuses me.. I have absolutely no clue how to do it based on what I know (see above)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(x,t) = ∫_0^t \theta(u) \exp(-\alpha(t-u) ) dB(u)
\\
= e^{-\alpha t} ∫_0^t \theta(u) \exp(\alpha u ) dB(u) 
$$
Now use the fact that $t \to e^{-\alpha t}$ is of finite variation and 
the **Ito formula for a product**:

> If $X,Y$ are two Ito processes then so is $XY$:
>   $$
> dX_t = a_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t
> \\
> dX_t = b_t dt + \sigma'_t dB_t
> \\
> d(XY)_ t = X_t dY_t + Y_t dX_t +  \sigma_t\sigma'_t dt
> $$

$$
dg(x,t) 
 = d(e^{-\alpha t})∫_0^t \theta(u) \exp(\alpha u ) dB(u)
+ e^{-\alpha t} d\left[∫_0^t \theta(u) \exp(\alpha u ) dB(u)\right]
\\
=
-\alpha e^{-\alpha t} dt ∫_0^t \theta(u) \exp(\alpha u ) dB(u) 
+ e^{-\alpha t}  \theta(t) \exp(\alpha t ) dB(t) + 0
\\
= -\alpha e^{-\alpha t} dt ∫_0^t \theta(u) \exp(\alpha u ) dB(u) 
+  \theta(t) dB(t) 
$$

Comment: Thanks.. how did you get $ e^{-\alpha t}  \theta(t) \exp(\alpha t ) dB(t) $ ?

Comment: I don't really see how you applied / used the Ito formula for a product?

Comment: with $e^{-\alpha t} \times ∫_0^t \theta(u) \exp(\alpha u ) dB(u) $

Comment: your first term is the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt $  term (in my grey box), but what is your second term? Thanks

Comment: and I still don't understand why you mention something about $ d(X Y)_t$. Can you explain that please?

Comment: I edited with more explicit explanations. tell me if it's okay

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I now see that your method works. But it seems different from the formula in my grey box. Can you maybe explain the relation between my formula and your method?

Comment: this is your formula with multivariate version: f(x,y) = xy

Comment: see [here](http://mplab.ucsd.edu/tutorials/sde.pdf) page 13.

Comment: great thanks for your help